# Parsing a repeated key, value delimetered by a colon (by regex or other text parsing process)

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am working in Python and using regex module. Happy to use alternate parsing methods for the following though. In fact, I try to avoid regex where I can.

I am happy with the python needed to solve the problem. I am only struggling with the regex pattern.

Some sample data (each line is supplied separately):

```
This is a key : this_is_an_id_related_to_this_value   Sometimes just the ID present but in some cases a basic sentence delimited by more than one space          Second key : id2   description where I assume only one space is allowed, no other assumptions on what the content might contain                     <relates_to_id>
Container : 123ABC   <view5>
Container : A1B2   Some Sample Data Located at Rack 6          Storage Place : 1234   Think about another random description                     <view3>
Container : AbACc123   Some more sample data with some description          Storage Place : B14hb14h   Blah Blah Blah                     <view5>
Container : C0Nt41n3r8   Cleanup on isle 9          Storage Place : DEDE123   Storage Fridge 2                     <view8>
Container : Eb0l4   Infectious disease test rack 2          Storage Place : G3nX   XOXO Special Fridge 4                  Col : 8   Row : 3   <view8>
```

This should translate to:

```py
[
  {
    "This is a key": {
      "id": "this_is_an_id_related_to_this_value",
      "description": "Sometimes just the ID present but in some cases a basic sentence delimited by more than one space"
    },
    "Second key": {
      "id": "id2",
      "description": "description where I assume only one space is allowed, no other assumptions on what the content might contain"
    },
    "relates_to": "relates_to_id"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "123ABC"
    },
    "relates_to": "view5"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "A1B2",
      "description": "Some Sample Data Located at Rack 6"
    },
    "Storage Place": {
      "id": "1234",
      "description": "Think about another random description"
    },
    "relates_to": "view3"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "AbACc123",
      "description": "Some more sample data with some description"
    },
    "Storage Place": {
      "id": "B14hb14h",
      "description": "Blah Blah Blah"
    },
    "relates_to": "view5"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "C0Nt41n3r8",
      "description": "Cleanup on isle 9"
    },
    "Storage Place": {
      "id": "DEDE123",
      "description": "Storage Fridge 2"
    },
    "relates_to": "view8"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "Eb0l4",
      "description": "Infectious disease test rack 2"
    },
    "Storage Place": {
      "id": "G3nX",
      "description": "XOXO Special Fridge 4"
    },
    "Col": 8,
    "Row": 3,
    "relates_to": "view8"
  },
]
```

At this stage I am happy with a solution that only takes care of parent key, values, e.g.

```py
[
  {
    "This is a key": "this_is_an_id_related_to_this_value   Sometimes just the ID present but in some cases a basic sentence delimited by more than one space",
    "Second key": "id2   description where I assume only one space is allowed, no other assumptions on what the content might contain",
    "relates_to": "relates_to_id"
  },
  # ...
]
```

I am confident I can figure out the rest, and when I do I will supply it as an alternate answer.

---

Here is what I have tried using regex, [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/3bW4X9/1)

`(?<key>((?! +)[A-Za-z]*\s?)*):(?<value>.*)`

I thought wrapping the above in ()* would take key of the `key : value` repetition. But it fails, [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/JigpxT/1)

This almost gets what I want but I fail to repeat the `key : value` repetition, [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/NzVUrr/1)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below regex. This will repetitively fetch `key`, `id`, `description` and `relates_to`

```regex
(?:(?P<key>.*?)\s*?:\s*?(?P<id>\S.*?)\s{3,}(?:(?P<desc>.*?)\s{4,})?)*?(?:<(?P<relates>.*?)>)?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l0PaBp/3)

Please use below code to convert the result into json format

**Code**

```py
import re
a="""This is a key : this_is_an_id_related_to_this_value   Sometimes just the ID present but in some cases a basic sentence delimited by more than one space          Second key : id2   description where I assume only one space is allowed, no other assumptions on what the content might contain                     <relates_to_id>
Container : 123ABC   <view5>
Container : A1B2   Some Sample Data Located at Rack 6          Storage Place : 1234   Think about another random description                     <view3>
Container : AbACc123   Some more sample data with some description          Storage Place : B14hb14h   Blah Blah Blah                     <view5>
Container : C0Nt41n3r8   Cleanup on isle 9          Storage Place : DEDE123   Storage Fridge 2                     <view8>
Container : Eb0l4   Infectious disease test rack 2          Storage Place : G3nX   XOXO Special Fridge 4                  Col : 8   Row : 3   <view8>
"""
result=re.findall("(?:(?P<key>.*?)\s*?:\s*?(?P<id>\S.*?)\s{3,}(?:(?P<desc>.*?)\s{4,})?)*?(?:<(?P<relates>.*?)>)?",a)
output=[]
temp={}
for part in result:
    if part[0]:
        if part[1] and part[2]:
            temp1={}
            temp1.update({"id":part[1]})
            temp1.update({"description":part[2]})
        elif part[1]:
            temp1=part[1]
        else:
            pass
        if temp1:
            temp.update({part[0]:temp1})
        if part[3]:
            temp.update({"relates_to":part[3]})
            output.append(temp)
            temp={}

print(output)
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "This is a key": {
      "id": "this_is_an_id_related_to_this_value",
      "description": "Sometimes just the ID present but in some cases a basic sentence delimited by more than one space"
    },
    "Second key": {
      "id": "id2",
      "description": "description where I assume only one space is allowed, no other assumptions on what the content might contain"
    },
    "relates_to": "relates_to_id"
  },
  {
    "Container": "123ABC",
    "relates_to": "view5"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "A1B2",
      "description": "Some Sample Data Located at Rack 6"
    },
    "Storage Place": {
      "id": "1234",
      "description": "Think about another random description"
    },
    "relates_to": "view3"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "AbACc123",
      "description": "Some more sample data with some description"
    },
    "Storage Place": {
      "id": "B14hb14h",
      "description": "Blah Blah Blah"
    },
    "relates_to": "view5"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "C0Nt41n3r8",
      "description": "Cleanup on isle 9"
    },
    "Storage Place": {
      "id": "DEDE123",
      "description": "Storage Fridge 2"
    },
    "relates_to": "view8"
  },
  {
    "Container": {
      "id": "Eb0l4",
      "description": "Infectious disease test rack 2"
    },
    "Storage Place": {
      "id": "G3nX",
      "description": "XOXO Special Fridge 4"
    },
    "Col": "8",
    "Row": "3",
    "relates_to": "view8"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this I think will work for me. With the real data I just have to make sure I assert everything is matched and that everything relevant is grouped. I came up with a more generic example that doesn't fit in your current answer, I am working on adapting to match that.

`key which can have anything except 2 or more spaces or an alternative whitespace character : val1 val1.1 val1.2  val2(notice 2 or more spaces preceding) val2.2                   val3                 val99+           key2 : val1 val1.1 val1.2           key99+ : val1 val1.1 val1.2 val1.3          val... <x>`